# How to save a list in a csv file via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, excel, backup, csv

I have a SharePoint ***online*** list with more than 9000 items and 22 column. The list is being populated on daily basis.

I am taking backup manually every morning by saving the list as excel file in the document library and in my local computer.

I need a Powershell script for SharePoint Online to save my list as xml file and then I can create a windows task to run it daily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell for SharePoint Online has really limited capabilities at the moment. There is no one liner to automate this task. But you can use CSOM inside your scripts.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint.Client') | Out-Null

$login = 'test@test.onmicrosoft.com'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$webUrl = 'https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/'
$listName = 'My List'

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $webUrl
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials $login, $password

$web = $context.Web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$items = $list.GetItems($query)

$context.Load($items)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$items | Select @{ L = "Title"; E = { $_["Title"] } }, @{ L = "Created"; E = { $_["Created"] } } | Export-Csv -Path export.csv
```

Of course it is far from final solution. There are following issues with the script:

- It loads data from all fields. Consider using `ViewFields` with the query to limit data loaded from database.
- It loads all items from list which may cause SharePoint to denny your request if it exceeds trottling limits. Consider using `RowLimit` and paging.
- In last line you can select required fields. You can also use one of `ConvertTo-*` methods to format your result.
- Credentials are stored as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample that explains the syntax:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://sp.dev/subsite" -ItemUrl "/subsite/lists/List Title here" -path "c:\output\tempfile.csv"
```

> Some Where Options:
>
> **Identity:** full url (absolute) of the site where the list exists
>
> **ItemUrl:**  relative path of the list from subsite level. Do not forget to include the leading “/”
>
> **Path:** path of the output file to save the data in. This does not need any extension but I usually give it .txt.
>
> There are lot more additional parameters but above are the minimum for
>   copying a list

For more details please refer to below links:

[How To Export/Import a List Using PowerShell](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-to-export-import-a-list-using-powershell)

[Use Windows PowerShell to export a site, list, or document library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee428293(v=office.14).aspx#section1)

Comment: This will only work for on-prem env. Question is about SharePoint Online.

Comment: You are right @dstarkowski, this will not work on SharePoint online!