# Export SharePoint Online list to csv via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I tried to export a SharePoint **Online** list to .csv by using this script:
 [How to save a list in a csv file via Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158430/how-to-save-a-list-in-a-csv-file-via-powershell)

Below is the script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint.Client') | Out-Null

$login = 'test@test.onmicrosoft.com'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$webUrl = 'https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/'
$listName = 'My List'

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $webUrl
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials $login, $password

$web = $context.Web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$items = $list.GetItems($query)

$context.Load($items)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$items | Select @{ L = "Title"; E = { $_["Title"] } }, @{ L = "Created"; E = { $_["Created"] } } | Export-Csv -Path export.csv
```

but I always get this Error:

> Cannot contact site at the specified URL
>   `https://sharepoint.sharepoint.com/Lists/demolist/`. There is no Web 
>   named "`/Lists/demolist/_vti_bin/sites.asmx`".

When I try to load the site `"manually"` I can load it.

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: did you download `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`? If so, then add path in your script

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish your requirement, you need following component locally.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
```

So download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

I have tried following script and it worked.

```
Add-Type -Path "LocalPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

$webUrl = "https://XXX.sharepoint.com"

$listName = "List Name"

$login = "xxx@yyy.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString


$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $webUrl
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials $login, $password

$web = $context.Web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$items = $list.GetItems($query)

$context.Load($items)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$items | Select @{ L = "Title"; E = { $_["Title"] } }, @{ L = "Created"; E = { $_["Created"] } } | Export-Csv -Path d:\export.csv
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to take the credentials/identity of the user account being used to run the script and use these to make the call to SharePoint Online? This would be ideal for us as it would prevent the need for storing the password in the script or for prompting the user.