# SharePoint Online list view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, csom

I need to access a list with 40,000 items and populate that data into a csv. How can I do this using caml?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158430/how-to-save-a-list-in-a-csv-file-via-powershell

Answer (score 0):

There are two available solutions from the Office Patterns and Practices:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ListViewThreshold.JSOMAndREST

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ListViewThreshold